# Laravel DB Query : Get One to Many Multidimentional Array Result

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm new to Laravel,
let me straight forward to the question.

Suppose I have 'Posts' table and 'Comments' table

And the first 'Post' has 3 comments,

What is the best query method to achieve this kind of result

```
Post => (
   [0]=> array (
      [id]=>1
      [content]=> This is my first Post!
      [comments]=> array(
         [0]=>array(
            [id]=>1
            [post_id]=>1
            [content]=> First comment!
         )

         [1]=>array(
            [id]=>2
            [post_id]=>1
            [content]=> Second comment!
         )

         [2]=>array(
            [id]=>3
            [post_id]=>1
            [content]=> Third comment!
         )


      )
   )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Eager load the relationship:

```
$posts = Post::with('comments')->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: Mazenin : please help :(

Comment: @Angger you need to define `hasMany()` relationship first to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eloquent relationships. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many.

The example is exactly what you're looking for! (:

Comment: No, It only return comments values